# Check if query returns anything in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have this code:

```
    q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE user_id = :1", current_user.user_id())
    user_data = q.get()

    if not user_data:
        logging.error('a')
        user_data = UserData(user_id = current_user.user_id(),
                             primary_email = current_email
                             )
        user_data.put()
    else:
        logging.error(pprint.pprint(user_data))
```

It is logging "None" because it's running the else. Shouldn't "None" be caught by the "if not user_data"?

Comment: Seems like it should be. Silly question, but have you verified that it is indeed that line returning `None`?

Answer (score 0):

The output you see differs from what I see running in the local console (I filled in some gaps from your provided code):

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class UserData(db.Model):
  user_id = db.StringProperty()

u = UserData()
u.user_id = "Foo"
u.put()

q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE user_id = :1", "Bar")
user_data = q.get()

if not user_data:
  print "Not"
else:
  print "Is"
```

This prints:

```
Not
```

Perhaps some other part of your code is having an unintended side-effect?

Comment: My problem apparently was a broken datastore entry which contained "None" but was still a datastore entry. When I replaced my query argument with "Bar" it returned the actual string "None" and worked as expected.